# Can't fetch the profile name using Selenium after logging in using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I've written a script in Python to get only the name visible in my profile in SO. The thing is I would like to log in that site using requests module and once I'm logged in I wish to get the profile name using Selenium. The bottom line is -- when I get the profile URL, I would like that URL to be reused by Selenium to fetch the profile name.

This working solution using ***requests***:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f"

req = requests.get(url)
sauce = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
fkey = sauce.select_one("[name='fkey']")['value']
payload = {
    'fkey': fkey,
    'ssrc': 'head',
    'email': my_username,
    'password': my_password,
    'oauth_version':'', 
    'oauth_server':'' 
    }
res = requests.post(url,data=payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
item = soup.select_one("div[class^='gravatar-wrapper-']").get("title")
print(item)
```

***What I wish to do now is:***

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

req = requests.get(url)
sauce = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
fkey = sauce.select_one("[name='fkey']")['value']
payload = {
    'fkey': fkey,
    'ssrc': 'head',
    'email': my_username,
    'password': my_password,
    'oauth_version':'', 
    'oauth_server':'' 
    }
res = requests.post(url,data=payload)
cookie_item = [{'name':name, 'value':value} for name,value in req.cookies.items()]
driver.add_cookie(cookie_item[0])
driver.get(res.url)
item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class^='gravatar-wrapper-']").get_attribute("title")
print(item)
```

Upon execution I encounter the following error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unable to set cookie
```

***How can I fetch the profile name using Selenium by re-using profile url derived from requests?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably more appropriate to use the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) rather than scrape the site, but in any case..

There are a few problems:

1. You will sometimes get a captcha challenge.
2. Leaving the default `requests` headers increases the odds of getting a captcha, so override it with one from a traditional browser.
3. You need to use `requests.Session()` to maintain the cookies from both of the first two requests.
4. Before adding the cookies from the `requests` session, you need to make an initial request with webdriver and clear any created cookies.

Taking those things into account, I was able to get it to work with the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": (
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) "
        "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.81 Safari/537.36"
    )
}

s = requests.Session()

req = s.get(url, headers=headers)
payload = {
    "fkey": BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml").select_one("[name='fkey']")["value"],
    "email": "YOUR_EMAIL",
    "password": "YOUR_PASSWORD",
}

res = s.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)

if "captcha" in res.url:
    raise ValueError("Encountered captcha")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    driver.get(res.url)
    driver.delete_all_cookies()

    for cookie in s.cookies.items():
        driver.add_cookie({"name": cookie[0], "value": cookie[1]})

    driver.get(res.url)

    item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class^='gravatar-wrapper-']")
    print(item.get_attribute("title"))
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: driver.delete_all_cookies() isn't needed... Chrome will start with a fresh profile and no cookies already.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg The call to `driver.get()` that immediately precedes it creates cookies

Answer (score 3):

You need to be on the domain that the cookie will be valid for.

Before calling `driver.add_cookie()`, you must first navigate to [any] page from that domain... so, make an additional call to `driver.get(url)` before attempting to add cookies.  Even an error page will suffice:

`driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/404')`

for example...

change this in your code:

```
driver.add_cookie(cookie_item[0])
driver.get(res.url)
```

to this:

```
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/404')
driver.add_cookie(cookie_item[0])
driver.get(res.url)
```

Comment: Your suggestion is unclear to me and for this reason I can't make it to work @Corey Goldberg. Could you please tell how the full-fledged code might look like? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't still fetch the profile name. Now the script throws `no such element: Unable to locate element` error.

Comment: you also need to wait for the element.  use `WebDriverWait`

Comment: Even if I wait a long time, the script won't find that element because this `driver.get(res.url)` never leads me to the already logged in page. I suppose the approach should be somewhat different anywhere within the script than what you have suggested. Thanks.